# Are users told about the existence of English Language Learners on their first post?

Tags: discussion, site

When a user wants to post their first question here, are they told that our sister site English Language Learners exists and they should consider which of the two sites would be most appropriate for their question?

If not, should this be the case?

Answer (score 8):

> When a user wants to post their first question here, are they told that our sister site English Language Learners exists […]?

As a matter of fact they are, on the right hand side of the **[Ask a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** page  there is a notice. But whether new contributors  *notice* or acknowledge its existence, despite the bold formatting and the link in blue, is open to debate.

[image]

> If your question is about learning English, **[ask it on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/https://)** instead.

Comment: Maybe that message is part of the problem. Non-native speakers who ask on this site are generally interested in __using__ English correctly. If they ask about __learning__ English (for example, _What's the best way to learn vocabulary?_), they should be directed to the _Language Learning_ site, not to _ELL_.

Comment: @Shoe could very well be.  On the other hand, we don't know how many newcomers have actually read or *seen* that notice and redirected their efforts to ELL. "We" don't know how effective or ineffective that notice is but it's telling that the OP wasn't aware of it despite having posted a fair number of questions themself.

Comment: I notice that actually comes up for me as well, I just wasn't aware of it. The big "Ask a question" part in the middle shouts "Look at me!" but the side panel is very easy to overlook. Also, how many first time users would know what ELL is?

Comment: Note that that side panel is not displayed in the mobile version of the site, at least, not for logged in users. When a user that is not logged in clicks "Ask" they do get an information screen before the actual Ask screen, but I can't tell if that is also shown to users with new accounts.